# How can I create a user using Next js 13 and Sanity.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13, sanity

I have been trying to create a user and add it to the collection of user in sanity.io when ever a form is filled but I have been struggling and is not working.

**This is the `handleSubmit` function:**

```
const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (firstName === "" || surname === "" || email === "" || phone === "" || password === "") {
      console.log("Enter fields");
      return;
    }
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/register", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ firstName, surname, email, phone, password }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const resp = await response.json();
        console.log(resp);
      } else {
        console.error("Response not okay:", response);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during request:", error);
    }
  };
```

**And this is the api route:**
The post request is in the api route. Then, I created a folder in the `api route` 'register' and create a file `route.ts`: `api/register`. The code below:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { createClient, type ClientConfig } from "@sanity/client";

const config: ClientConfig = {
  projectId: process.env.SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  dataset: process.env.SANITY_DATASET,
  useCdn: true,
  apiVersion: process.env.SANITY_API_VERSION,
};
const client = createClient(config);

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const { firstName, surname, email, password, phone } = await req.json();

  if (!firstName || !surname || !email || !password || !phone) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Missing required data" });
  }

  const newUser = await client.create({
    _type: "user",
    firstName,
    surname,
    email,
    password,
    phone,
  });
  return NextResponse.json(newUser);
}
```